# Three pieces vs Queen in the opening

Tags: opening, theory

Please, does someone have good information on the Grünfeld Defence, Russian System, three minor pieces vs Queen variation?

Comment: Hi Stefano, can you please provide some more details?  At the very least, the moves for the variation with the queen sacrifice.